# How to import or() method of firestore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I can see the docs of or() [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#or) but when I use it as :

```
    const firestore=require("firebase/firestore");
 const {or} =firestore;
 var q1=query(collectionObj,or(where("FID","==",id),where("SID","==",id)));
```

node complains that "or is not a function".

the docs are also really not helpful because they don't mention the exact module where they are defined.

Comment: Isn't it the same import that you use for all the other Firestore functions?